# How to use plotly in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I am trying to add graph for the output which i have generated using shiny. I am getting error for graph generation. Can someone please have a look and assist. The bar graph parameters are calculation based outputs generated from calculations.

```
server
output$graph<- renderPlotly({

  plotly( x= c(as.numeric(input$contract), round(frateperton()), differencerate()),

         y= c('Contract Rate', 'ZBC Rate', 'Difference'),

         name = "Zero Based Rate Chart",

         type = "bar")

})


UI
plotlyOutput("graph"),
```

Answer (score 38):

First of all, two remarks on your post :

- it is not reproducible, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to learn what a reproducible example is and how to make one
- clearly you haven't searched enough. Typing "r shiny plotly output" in any search engine gives several potential solutions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980999/change-plotly-chart-y-variable-based-on-selectinput) for example).

To avoid duplicated posts, please consider these two points next time.

Now, here's the answer (using `iris` data since your example is not reproducible):

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("choice", "Choose", choices = names(iris), selected = NULL),
  plotlyOutput("graph")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$graph <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(iris, x = ~get(input$choice), y = ~Sepal.Length, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @mayank14: This answer should be marked as correct.